# How can I get the statusbar height in nativescript?

Tags: android, ios, nativescript, styling

Android and iOS have different sized status bars for different versions of their OS.  Using native script, how can I figure out what this height is?

I need it so I can add a padding to the top of my app which is equal in size to the status bar, otherwise it overlaps varying amounts of my app content.

Comment: With Android your content wouldn't overlap at all with status bar. At least on iOS in a fullscreen application, your content would, but not on Android unless you are forcing the window by updating the flags. Are you doing so?

Comment: I'm not forcing anything, but my emulator is definitely showing overlap.  In any case, it all seems to vary a bit from phone to phone to emulator and back.

Comment: Can you share a Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced?

Comment: Do you not agree that there is a top bar which sometimes overlaps the app content?

Comment: Sorry, I wouldn't as you are not explicitly setting any flag in your window to force it so which is why I asked for Playground sample.

Comment: In my case, where for one page I implement own status bar, I also need to get the status bar height, so it's header be consistent within all pages. For now, I only find how to get it for Android from the Theme object, but how to get it for iOS still is the question (I really do not wat hardcode it as constant [iOS Design](https://kapeli.com/cheat_sheets/iOS_Design.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/index)).

Comment: @seph-reed  Did you figure this out? I'd also like to figure out a way to calculate status bar height. Android phones with notches or hole punches have different size statusbars, and I need to know the height  to apply the proper padding to my header if I want to draw under the status bar

Comment: I'm pretty sure I just ended up using conditional css on the top padding, and android and ios have been consistent enough with their sizing that it works out.